# Is this possible to embedded an image in HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is that HTML form only support pure text only? Can I use some JS / CSS trick to let the HTML form have image embedded?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? do you want to display an image in a form? inside a form element? from an external site? as text instead of a link to a file? or something else?

Comment: Do you want to send an image via POST? I dont understand your question

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "image embedded"?

If it's only for decoration, you can put it before or after the form and position it with CSS as needed.

If you mean, submit an image (or any kind of file) then use input type="file".

Regarding image directly in form, it may work but I'm not sure the document will validate. Better check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Image tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_images.asp

Comment: I think he wants to embed the image into the html source, an IMG tag links to an 'external' image.

Comment: I think he wants to send an image to the server.

Comment: I think he doesn't knows what he wants

Answer (score 0):

If you mean embedded image in base64 for example, it is not possible. 
You have to link a file and you cannot create a file in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This Html Code Works Like Img But Can Show Any File Your Browser Supports.
I Tested This iframe Myself.

```html
<iframe src="(Your Base 64 Code)"></iframe>
```

This Site is Not My Creation.
[Use This Link To Convert Any File To Base64](http://jpillora.com/base64-encoder/)